# how can I call a custom hamcrest matcher?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I want to check when a mock is called with a `realtimeUpdate` which `currentTime` field equals some `LocalDateTime`:

I want to run such code with a custom matcher:

```
verify(mockServerApi).sendUpdate(new TimeMatcher().isTimeEqual(update, localDateTime2));
```

but I have a compilation error when I try to run with this custom matcher.

How can I fix this?

```
public class TimeMatcher {

    public Matcher<RealtimeUpdate> isTimeEqual(RealtimeUpdate realtimeUpdate, final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return new BaseMatcher<RealtimeUpdate>() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(final Object item) {
                final RealtimeUpdate realtimeUpdate = (RealtimeUpdate) item;
                return realtimeUpdate.currentTime.equalTo(localDateTime);
            }
```

this is the method signature

```
void sendRealTimeUpdate(RealtimeUpdate realtimeUpdate);
```

and this is the compilation error:

[image]

Comment: http://www.planetgeek.ch/2012/03/07/create-your-own-matcher/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could proceed

The class `TimeMatcher`, you need only the `LocalDateTime`

```
public class TimeMatcher {
    public static Matcher<RealtimeUpdate> isTimeEqual(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return new BaseMatcher<RealtimeUpdate>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(final Description description) {
                description.appendText("Date doesn't match with "+ localDateTime);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(final Object item) {
                final RealtimeUpdate realtimeUpdate = (RealtimeUpdate) item;
                return realtimeUpdate.currentTime.isEqual(localDateTime);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The test:

```
Mockito.verify(mockRoutingServerApi).sendRealTimeUpdate(
    new ThreadSafeMockingProgress().getArgumentMatcherStorage()
        .reportMatcher(TimeMatcher.isTimeEqual(localDateTime2))
        .returnFor(RealtimeUpdate.class));
```

You need to use `returnFor` to provide the argument type which is `RealtimeUpdate` as expected by `sendRealTimeUpdate`

This is equivalent to:

```
Mockito.verify(mockRoutingServerApi).sendRealTimeUpdate(
    Matchers.argThat(TimeMatcher.isTimeEqual(localDateTime2))
);
```

Comment: pay attention that  `sendRealTimeUpdate(RealtimeUpdate realtimeUpdate)` and not `localDateTime2 ` as a param

Comment: `You need to use returnFor to return an object of type` even if I just want to verify the param send to method call? I don't want to override a method now, just verify it was called with a specific argument.

Comment: is it a must to use `new ThreadSafeMockingProgress().getArgumentMatcherStorage()
        .reportMatcher` ? Is my syntax wrong (without it) ?

Comment: yes new ThreadSafeMockingProgress().getArgumentMatcherStorage() is a mandatory otherwise it cannot work

Comment: how is it differ than `argThat()` ?

Comment: behind the scene it does the same thing indeed use argThat for a better readibility